# ColdFusion Builder 2 custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: coldfusionbuilder

I would like to know if it is possible to create a custom keyboard shortcut in CF Builder 2 and have selected text retained and placed within the code of the inserted text.  Sort of like a custom wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite, but you can create [snippets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/Using/WS0ef8c004658c1089-2cf13501121af8ece2c-7ffb.html#WS0ef8c004658c1089-2cf13501121af8ece2c-7ffa) and bind them to some trigger text.  [Matt Gifford's article on snippets](http://www.mattgifford.co.uk/coldfusion-builder-snippets) is more useful than the official documentation.